# Matrix table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, matrix, relationship

I have three tables:

- Table `tCity`

  ```
  (Id int, City nvarchar(50))
  ```
- Table `tLocation`

  ```
  (Id int, Location nvarchar(50))
  ```
- Table `tCityLocation`

  ```
  (Id int, CityId int, LocationId int)
  ```

I would like to generate matrix table like in image below.

If City belongs to location-> in appropriate cell in table, char X will be written down.

I would like to about any sophisticated approach how to reach it. I had issue in similar logic and processed by iteration in cursors with dynamically added column to result set table.

Exists any sophisticated approach instead of cursor and dynamically added column?

Thank you.

[image: ResultSet]

SQL server, I am working in MSSMS

Comment: What's your RMDB?

Comment: That's a bad DB structure. Continents and countries should not be stored in the same table.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: There are no matrix tables, in any database. Tables aren't spreadsheets. They represent a relation between the items stored in their columns.

Comment: If you want to create a matrix view for display, it's *easier* to transpose the data on the client. In SQL you'll have to determine the columns in advance (relations can't have arbitrary columns/entity types) and use a PIVOT clause. That's still not a true matrix table though. On the other hand, in HTML you could easily create a matrix rom a `List<(x,y,value)>` using a loop to emit the `<th>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` elements

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
DECLARE @DymanimcTSQLSatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@DynamicColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DynamicColumns = STUFF
                      (
                        (
                            SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Location])
                            FROM tLocation
                            GROUP BY [Location] 
                            ORDER BY [Location] 
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                        ,1
                        ,1
                        ,''
                     );

SET @DymanimcTSQLSatement = N'
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT L.Location
          ,C.City
          ,1
    FROM tCityLocation CL
    INNER JOIN tLocation L
        ON CL.[LocationId] = L.[id]
    INNER JOIN tCity C
        ON CL.[CityId] = C.[id]
) DS (country, city, value)
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [country] IN (' + @DynamicColumns +')
) PVT;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DymanimcTSQLSatement;
```

[image]

and here is the data I have used:

```
-- Creating Table tCity
CREATE TABLE tCity (
    Id int,
    City nvarchar(50)
);

-- Populating Table tCity with 10 records
INSERT INTO tCity (Id, City) VALUES (1, 'New York');
INSERT INTO tCity (Id, City) VALUES (2, 'Los Angeles');
INSERT INTO tCity (Id, City) VALUES (3, 'Paris');
INSERT INTO tCity (Id, City) VALUES (4, 'Tokyo');
INSERT INTO tCity (Id, City) VALUES (5, 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO tCity (Id, City) VALUES (6, 'Philadelphia');
INSERT INTO tCity (Id, City) VALUES (7, 'Rio de Janeiro');
INSERT INTO tCity (Id, City) VALUES (8, 'Cape Town');
INSERT INTO tCity (Id, City) VALUES (9, 'Beijing');
INSERT INTO tCity (Id, City) VALUES (10, 'Singapore');

-- Creating Table tLocation
CREATE TABLE tLocation (
    Id int,
    Location nvarchar(50)
);

-- Populating Table tLocation with 10 records
INSERT INTO tLocation (Id, Location) VALUES (1, 'United States');
INSERT INTO tLocation (Id, Location) VALUES (2, 'United States');
INSERT INTO tLocation (Id, Location) VALUES (3, 'France');
INSERT INTO tLocation (Id, Location) VALUES (4, 'Japan');
INSERT INTO tLocation (Id, Location) VALUES (5, 'Australia');
INSERT INTO tLocation (Id, Location) VALUES (6, 'United States');
INSERT INTO tLocation (Id, Location) VALUES (7, 'Brazil');
INSERT INTO tLocation (Id, Location) VALUES (8, 'South Africa');
INSERT INTO tLocation (Id, Location) VALUES (9, 'China');
INSERT INTO tLocation (Id, Location) VALUES (10, 'Singapore');

-- Creating Table tCityLocation
CREATE TABLE tCityLocation (
    Id int,
    CityId int,
    LocationId int
);


INSERT INTO tCityLocation (Id, CityId, LocationId)
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tCity.Id), 
    tCity.Id, tLocation.Id
FROM tCity 
JOIN tLocation 
ON tCity.Id = tLocation.Id;
```

---

The idea is to built a dynamic PIVOT, where the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) columns are the unique countries (in your case locations). If your SQL Server supports [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), you can do this in different way:

```
SELECT @DynamicColumns = STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME([Location]) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Location])
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [Location]
    FROM tLocation
) DS ([Location]);
```

Comment: Be great if your answer also contained an explanation as to how it works in addition to the solution.

Comment: The XML trick is no longer needed in supported SQL Server versions. The answer would be easier to understand if `STRING_AGG` was used

Answer (score 0):

Better way for answer to this question use pivot

First I get list Location of table Location

Second I get list Location of table tLocation For use in select
Because I need to use ISNULL for replace null with space

after use pivot for get result

result :Rows include List  City and Column include Location

| city | Asia | CRezah Rep. | Europe | France | GB | Germany | Japan | N.America | USA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x |
| Prague |  | x | x |  |  | x |  |  |  |
| London |  |  | x |  | x |  |  |  |  |
| Tokio | x |  |  |  |  |  | x |  |  |

```
--Get List Columns for Pivot

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@scols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Location)  from tLocation
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')   ,1,1,'' )
 
--can to use below Code for Replace null with space

select @scols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Location) +','' '') as '+  QUOTENAME(Location)
                 from tLocation  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'')
 
 set @query = 'SELECT  city ,'+@scols+' from 
             (
                select cl.CityId,c.City,l.Location,''X'' as Value from tCityLocation cl
                inner join tCity c on cl.CityId=c.Id
                inner join tLocation l on cl.LocationId=l.Id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
               max( value)  for Location in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            order by CityId
            '

execute(@query)
```

You can to insert the basic data with the following codes

```
create table tCity(Id int, City nvarchar(50))

create table tLocation(Id int, Location nvarchar(50))

create table tCityLocation(Id int, CityId int, LocationId int)

insert into tCity
(id,City)
select 1 as id,'NY' union all select 2 as id,'Prague'
union all select 3 as id,'London' union all select 4 as id,'Tokio'

insert into tLocation (id,Location)
select 1,'USA' union all select 2,'CRezah Rep.' union all select 3,'France' union all select 4,'GB'
union all select 5,'Germany' union all select 6,'Europe' union all select 7,'N.America'
union all select 9,'Asia' union all select 10,'Japan'

insert into tCityLocation
(id,CityId,LocationId)
select 1,1,1 union all select 2,1,7 union all select 3,2,2 union all select 4,2,6 union all select 5,3,4 union all
select 6,3,6 union all select 7,4,9 union all select 8,4,10
```

Comment: Please learn how to format your code as code using the backticks as shown in the editor.

Comment: Also when providing an answer, please provide an explanation in addition to working code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited this Post,if this post has problem ,please say to me.  @Dale K